# Why does custom urls work with UseConfiguration and not with ConfigureAppConfiguration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I was struggling to use custom `urls` for `Kestrel` and I finally found a combination of settings and builders that work but I'm really confused why does the following work:

```
var configuration =
    new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

var host =
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseContentRoot(contentRootPath)
        .UseConfiguration(configuration)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

but not this:

```
var host =
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseContentRoot(contentRootPath)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) => 
        { 
            builder.AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true); 
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

It just ignores the `hosting.json` file as if it wasn't there.

---

What is the difference between using your own builder vs. using the `ConfigureAppConfiguration` extension? Is there a rule of thumb when to use which?

Comment: This is by design, though this design does not make any sense to me: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1148

Comment: @Evk holy cow, thanks. I guess I asked google the wrong keywords and didn't find this git-issue...

Comment: It's and order of operations issue. UseConfiguration configures the host and server, where ConfigureAppConfiguration configures only the app.